# Inverse image of morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $\pi:X\to S$ be a flat morphism of noetherian separated schemes, and $E$, $F$ coherent sheaves on $S$. There is a canonical morphism of sheaves
$$\pi^*(\underline{Hom}(E,F))\longrightarrow \underline{Hom}(\pi^*(E),\pi^*(F)) .$$
Under which conditions on $\pi$ is it an isomorphism, for every $E$ and $F$ ?

Comment: This is always true. You can assume that $X$ and $Y$ are affine, so this becomes a classical (and simple) result of commutative algebra, see e.g. Bourbaki's *Commutative algebra* I, §2, Proposition 11.

Comment: @abx thank you very much